# How Davies–Meyer does work?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5, universal-hash

**I am here so if I asked something wrong or in the wrong way please let me know.**

How to hash compression large data into the fixed size of the string.

### **Edit:**

How Davies–Meyer does work?
Take the example of input as: "Hello this is a demo"

Comment: Note that hash functions themselves don't generate textual / hexadecimal strings, they generate binary / octet strings - in the case of the insecure MD5 hash it's 128 bits / 16 bytes in size. The conversion to hexadecimals is common (if the hash needs to be human readable) but tool specific.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ok well still now answer my question like hash can convert any size of data to a fixed binary... The question is how???

Comment: Have you looked at the [Davies-Meyer construction on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies%E2%80%93Meyer)? If not, please do so. If you have, what specific part of it do you not understand?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes my question is answered, yeah but I am interested in the commemoration method if you have any other resources please mention

Comment: Instead of something being actively remembered it helps to think it as changes of state for each input block. Of course the input data is not retained, so I'm not sure what you mean with "commemoration".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes lol even I'm not sure what I mean with "commemoration" it was auto-correct, I mean, I am interested in the compression method if you have any other resources please mention